# NullPointerException in getHibernateLazyInitializer of entity class

Tags: java, hibernate, javassist

I'm experiencing the following exception:

```
     java.lang.NullPointerException 
     at javassist.util.proxy.RuntimeSupport$DefaultMethodHandler.invoke(RuntimeSupport.java:38)
     at com.Customer_$$_javassist_1.getHibernateLazyInitializer(Customer_$$_javassist_1.java)
     at org.hibernate.Hibernate.isInitialized(Hibernate.java:429)
     at org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.reassociateIfUninitializedProxy(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:530)
     at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.reassociateIfUninitializedProxy(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:99)
     at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:82)
     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:685)
     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:677)
     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:673)
     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$16.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:740)
     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(HibernateTemplate.java:737)
     at com.HibernateCustomerService.create(HibernateCustomerService.java:31)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
     at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
     at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
     at sun.proxy.$Proxy62.create(Unknown Source)
```

This tends to happen shortly after application startup under moderate/high load. Further Instantiation of the `com.Customer` class fail with the same exception so the application is effectively broken until we restart.

I've traced through the code and can't see how the `DefaultMethodHandler` would ever be invoked in `theCustomer_$$_javassist_1` since it's set in the `JavassistLazyInitializer`.

This is on Hibernate 3.6.8-Final with javassist 3.16.1

Has anyone seen this before? Is there any workaround possible?

Comment: Is it possible that Hibernate is trying to initialize something to null? For example you may have database inconsistency and what Hibernate thinks must be there in fact isn't.

Comment: don't think so - it looks like `setHandler` is not being called on the generated `Customer_$$_javassist_1a` leaving it to use the `RuntimeSupport.default_interceptor` which falls over when the above method is called

Comment: I have the same issue, how to solve it?